# SQL Server Nested CASE and OR in WHERE statement

Tags: sql-server, case, iif

I have been trying all day to figure out how to (properly) move a nested IIF statement from Access to SQL Server.

The query needs to evaluate a simple NULL/-1/1 (null/yes/no) combobox. If it is blank, it should bring back all records.  If YES (-1) then return `Demog.[LT Due Date] <= GETDATE()`.  If NO (1) then `Demog.[LT Due Date] >= GETDATE()`.

Here is the ACCESS SQL that works perfectly:

```
SELECT Demog.ID, Demog.[Long Term Date]
FROM Demog
WHERE (
(iif(Forms!Demog_Entry!cbox_LTPD=-1,Demog.[Long Term Date]<=Date(),
(iif(Forms!Demog_Entry!cbox_LTPD=0,Demog.[Long Term 
Date]>=Date(),isnull(Forms!Demog_Entry!cbox_LTPD))))));
```

And here is one of the SQL Server Codes I've tried: It evaluates the Null correctly, but if anything else it only returns `Demog.[LT Due Date] <= GETDATE()`.

```
Declare @LTPD as Bit
Set @LTPD = -1
SELECT Demog.ID, Demog.[LT Due Date]
FROM Demog
WHERE (1=(CASE WHEN @LTPD Is Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OR Demog.[LT Due Date] <= GETDATE())
```

I have also tried doing a combination of CASE and OR statements.  Here is what I have, but again, I just can't get it to evaluate all 3 states correctly.

```
WHERE (1=(CASE WHEN @LTPD Is Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OR 
(@LTPD=-1 AND Demog.[LT Due Date] <= GETDATE()) OR
(@LTPD=1 AND Demog.[LT Due Date] >= GETDATE()))
```

I also tried using IIF but could not make it work no matter what I did.  I'm assuming IIF works in the SELECT statement but not the WHERE statement?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 and later understand `IIF`... Example: `select 1
where iif(1=1,1,2)=1` will return 1 row, and `select 1
where iif(1=1,1,2)=2` will return 0 rows

Comment: you can use the `IF` function instead of `CASE`. Instead of `WHERE (1=(CASE WHEN @LTPD Is Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

you would have `WHERE (1=(IF(@LTPD IS NULL, 1, 0))`. Although the whole part in the where statement here is equivalent to `WHERE (@LTPD IS NULL)`

Comment: @SeanC - I'm really not sure how to implement that with my current code.  It needs to evaluate 3 conditions.  I can't even get the IIF statement to correctly evaluate 1 condition.  (Although I'm probably doing it wrong):  `WHERE IIF(@LTPD=-1,Demog.[LT Due Date]<=GETDATE(),Demog.[LT Due Date]<=GETDATE())`

Answer (score 1):

you might just need some ORs

```
select      Demog.ID, Demog.[Long Term Date]
from        Demog
where       (@LTPD IS NULL)
or          (@LTPD = -1 AND Demog.[Long Term Date]<=GetDate())
or          (@LTPD = 1  AND Demog.[Long Term Date]>=GetDate())
```

Comment: Functionally this is exactly the same as I have.  It does evaluate, but only ONE of the OR statements: `Demog.[LT Due Date] >= GETDATE()` When I change @LTPD it does not change the results.

Comment: @Cory Since you're using bit.. try 1 and 0 instead of 1 and -1 or use a smallint

Comment: @JamieD77-  YES!!! Thank you.  In all the copy/pasting/rewriting I must have forgotten that it's -1/0 - not -1/1.  THANK YOU!